# Switch Statement with enumerator

Tags: c#, winforms, switch-statement

I am trying to develop a Hotel Management System in Visual Studio C#. I have a combo box with hotel room types and a textbox with prices. I want that when a user chooses a room type, the text box displays the price of the room. I have tried to use a switch statement but it is giving me a Stackoverflow Exception. Can someone please help. Thanks

```
enum RoomType
{
    DoubleBB,
    SingleFullboard,
    SingleBB,
    DoubleFullboard,
    TwinBB,
    TwinFullboard
}

private void comboBoxroomtype_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RoomType myChoice = new RoomType();
    /*RoomType myChoice2 = RoomType.TwinFullboard;
    RoomType myChoice3 = RoomType.SingleBB;
    RoomType myChoice4 = RoomType.SingleFullboard;
    RoomType myChoice5 = RoomType.DoubleBB;
    RoomType myChoice6 = RoomType.DoubleFullboard;*/

    switch(myChoice)
    {
        case RoomType.TwinBB:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "TwinBB";
            txtroomrate.Text = "55 USD";
            goto case RoomType.TwinFullboard;
            break;

      case RoomType.TwinFullboard:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "TwinFullboard";
            txtroomrate.Text = "65 USD";
            goto case RoomType.DoubleBB;
            break;

        case RoomType.DoubleBB:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "DoubleBB";
            txtroomrate.Text = "50 USD";
            goto case RoomType.DoubleFullboard;
            break;

        case RoomType.DoubleFullboard:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "DoubleFullboard";
            txtroomrate.Text = "60 USD";
            goto case RoomType.SingleBB;
            break;

        case RoomType.SingleBB:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "SingleBB";
            txtroomrate.Text = "40 USD";
            goto case RoomType.SingleFullboard;
            break;

        case RoomType.SingleFullboard:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "SingleFullboard";
            txtroomrate.Text = "50 USD";
            break;
        default:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "";
            txtroomrate.Text = "";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: and in your case, you are definitely not using `goto` correctly. Try removing all uses and see what happens.

Comment: `goto` is going to cause very incorrect behavior here, but it may not be causing an infinite loop. Either way, this code is *really* wrong.

Comment: when i remove the goto , it only shows the first room type and room price but does not show other room types.

Comment: @walther What am I missing? It looks like each case goes to the next one, eventually terminating on the last case. Its *must* be causing the loop (due to the exception) but I don't see where it is recursing.

Comment: @walther I also don't see where it's getting caught in the infinite loop.  Care to point it out for me?

Comment: @user3628617 well yes, you don't use the selected index anywhere. Try using it instead of hardcoding the room type and your switch will work much better.

Comment: I'm not at all clear what your code is trying to do. At no point in your code are you checking which item in the combo box is selected, you're going through every option and setting your control values multiple times? Also, depending on which type of combo box you have, setting ComboBox.Text *causes* ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged to fire, thus causing your stack overflow...

Answer (score 3):

You can try Binding like this:

First create a class that encapsulates your mappings for each type of room and its desired price like this for example:

```
    public enum RoomType
    {
        DoubleBB,
        SingleFullboard,
        SingleBB,
        DoubleFullboard,
        TwinBB,
        TwinFullboard
    }

    public class Room
    {
        public RoomType Type { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
```

Next on your form you just use binding.I left some code commented out that we could have used to also format the data but for your case like this is probably ok:

```
        BindingSource source = new BindingSource();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            source.Add(new Room() { Type = RoomType.DoubleBB, Price = 50 });
            source.Add(new Room() { Type = RoomType.DoubleFullboard, Price = 60 });
            source.Add(new Room() { Type = RoomType.SingleBB, Price = 40 });
            source.Add(new Room() { Type = RoomType.SingleFullboard, Price = 50 });
            source.Add(new Room() { Type = RoomType.TwinBB, Price = 55 });
            source.Add(new Room() { Type = RoomType.TwinFullboard, Price = 65 });

            comboBox1.DataSource = source;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Type";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Price";

            Binding b = new Binding("Text", source, "Price");
            b.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(b_Format);

            textBox1.DataBindings.Add(b);
        }

        void b_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
        {
           e.Value = string.Format("{0:0 USD}", e.Value);
        }

        //private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //{
        //    textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "USD";
        //}
```

And thats all,every time you select another value from the combobox the text box will reflect that change.

Comment: @terrybozzio...i have tried your answer but its giving me errors on source and e.Value. Is there some additional information i need to input? Thanks

Comment: if you added the enum,class,and pasted the form code into your form(renaming the textbox and combobox to your own) it should run fine....

Comment: @terrybozzio...its running fine but instead of displaying the correct room prices, it displays 1 usd, 2usd, 3usd....in the Price text box...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what inclined you to use the go to statement. I think you just need to get rid of them and you will have what you want.

```
    switch(myChoice)
    {
        case RoomType.TwinBB:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "TwinBB";
            txtroomrate.Text = "55 USD";
            break;

      case RoomType.TwinFullboard:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "TwinFullboard";
            txtroomrate.Text = "65 USD";
            break;

        case RoomType.DoubleBB:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "DoubleBB";
            txtroomrate.Text = "50 USD";
            break;

        case RoomType.DoubleFullboard:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "DoubleFullboard";
            txtroomrate.Text = "60 USD";
            break;

        case RoomType.SingleBB:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "SingleBB";
            txtroomrate.Text = "40 USD";
            break;

        case RoomType.SingleFullboard:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "SingleFullboard";
            txtroomrate.Text = "50 USD";
            break;
        default:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "";
            txtroomrate.Text = "";
            break;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply delete the **break** keyword and it will work

```
 switch(myChoice)
    {
        case RoomType.TwinBB:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "TwinBB";
            txtroomrate.Text = "55 USD";
            goto case RoomType.TwinFullboard;


      case RoomType.TwinFullboard:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "TwinFullboard";
            txtroomrate.Text = "65 USD";
            goto case RoomType.DoubleBB;


        case RoomType.DoubleBB:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "DoubleBB";
            txtroomrate.Text = "50 USD";
            goto case RoomType.DoubleFullboard;


        case RoomType.DoubleFullboard:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "DoubleFullboard";
            txtroomrate.Text = "60 USD";
            goto case RoomType.SingleBB;


        case RoomType.SingleBB:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "SingleBB";
            txtroomrate.Text = "40 USD";
            goto case RoomType.SingleFullboard;


        case RoomType.SingleFullboard:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "SingleFullboard";
            txtroomrate.Text = "50 USD";
            break;
        default:
            comboBoxroomtype.Text = "";
            txtroomrate.Text = "";
            break;
    }
```

Because Falling through switch-cases can be achieved :

1. by having no code in a case
2. or using the special goto case
3. or goto default case.

Answer (score 0):

@user3385970's answer will work. But you can remove the `comboBoxroomtype.Text` setter from the switch statement and just use the `Enum.ToString()` method on the enum value:

```
comboBoxroomType.Text = myChoice.ToString();
switch(myChoice)
{
    case RoomType.TwinBB:
        txtroomrate.Text = "55 USD";
        break;

    case RoomType.TwinFullboard:
        txtroomrate.Text = "65 USD";
        break;

    case RoomType.DoubleFullboard:
        txtroomrate.Text = "60 USD";
        break;

    case RoomType.SingleBB:
        txtroomrate.Text = "40 USD";
        break;

    case RoomType.DoubleBB:
    case RoomType.SingleFullboard:
        txtroomrate.Text = "50 USD";
        break;

    default:
        comboBoxroomtype.Text = "";
        txtroomrate.Text = "";
        break;

}
```